# SwiftUI + Timer + AVPlayer - When audio playing, onReceive(timer) not triggered

Tags: swift, timer, swiftui, avplayer

I am having issue to make my timer (and my animation) to work properly. My timer is not triggered if `AVPlayer` is currently playing. As soon as I pause it, my timer is resuming...

I have an implementation of a `SlidingText` view. Basically just moving a text in its box from left to right and then right to left. This animation is triggered with a `Timer` every 5 seconds.
I have an `AVPlayer` playing something at the same time with a pause/play button.

This is the implementation of the `SlidingText`. And the `AVPlayer` is just being called with a button that triggers `player.play()` or `player.pause()`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SlidingText: View {
    let geometryProxy: GeometryProxy
    @Binding var text: String
    let font: Font

    @State private var animateSliding: Bool = false
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    private let slideDuration: Double = 3

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
            VStack(content: {
                Text(text)
                    .font(self.font)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.red)
            })
                .id("SlidingText-Animation")
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .frame(width: geometryProxy.size.width, alignment: animateSliding ? .trailing : .leading)
                .clipped()
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: slideDuration))
                .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                    self.animateSliding.toggle()
                })
        })
            .frame(width: self.geometryProxy.size.width, height: self.geometryProxy.size.height)
            .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong it the way I use the timer here?
Thanks for any future help!

Comment: It is not clear w/o complete context what's going on in run-time. Maybe your SlidingText is recreated during playback, so timer recreated... Try to keep timer outside of view.

Comment: My bad, I thought I might have implemented the `Timer` wrongly.
I am using this library for the player. https://github.com/jorgenhenrichsen/SwiftAudio

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I endup not using a timer because it is buggy.

for those interested it looks like this now, I am using the Animation properties.
No more interferences with the audio player.

```
struct SlidingText: View {
    let geometryProxy: GeometryProxy
    @Binding var text: String
    let font: Font

    @State private var animateSliding: Bool = false
    private let slideDelay: Double = 3
    private let slideDuration: Double = 6

    private var isTextLargerThanView: Bool {
        if text.size(forWidth: geometryProxy.size.width, andFont: font).width < geometryProxy.size.width {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading, content: {
            VStack(content: {
                Text(text)
                    .font(self.font)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Color.red)
            })
                .id("SlidingText-Animation")
                .fixedSize()
                .animation(Animation.linear(duration: slideDuration).delay(slideDelay).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
                .frame(width: geometryProxy.size.width,
                       alignment: isTextLargerThanView ? (animateSliding ? .trailing : .leading) : .center)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    self.animateSliding.toggle()
                })
        })
            .clipped()
    }
}
```